# Opserver Alerting that ElasticSearch Indexes and Shards are in Trouble

Tags: elasticsearch

We're using Opserver to monitor our ElasticSearch nodes. Recently it began alerting "1 Indexes in trouble" and "3 Shards in trouble". I can't seem to find any other information on these warnings. Searching on the involved indexes seems to be working properly.

Anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request the current status from ElasticSearch with the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

For the status per individual shard, use:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards'
```

For more information see [this](https://t37.net/how-to-fix-your-elasticsearch-cluster-stuck-in-initializing-shards-mode.html) link. For a nice graphical overview of your ES status, I recommend [Kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf)